# I 'm trying to show toast in fragment by two ways but it doesn't work.. I have attached a link to the project on GitHub

Tags: android-fragments, android-toast

https://github.com/Mussa-Adolai/MyRecycler/tree/edit_project

```
enter code here
```

from main activity

fun bottomNavClick(){
bottomNavigationView?.setOnItemSelectedListener(){

```
        when(it.itemId){
            R.id.home -> {

                chooseFragment(PersonFragment(),"HOME")

            }

            R.id.profile->{
                chooseFragment(RecyclerFragment(),"PROFILE")
                Toast.makeText(this,"recyclerFragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            }
        }
        true

    }


}
```

from fragment class

class PersonFragment : Fragment() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


    }


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?

): View? {

    Toast.makeText(activity,"PersonFragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_person, container, false)
}
```